# nfs is blocked by ufw even though ports are opened

Tags: 11.04, nfs, ufw

I've set up an nfsv4 server and it's working fine, however the firewall is blocking nfs even if port 2049 and 111 are open.

I know nfs uses some random ports that change at every boot, but how can i make them static so i can use nfs without disabling my firewall again?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I did some more research into this. Ubuntu is using the UFW, which is extremely easy to configure, yet very potent, at least for soho needs. So, the *rpc.mountd* listens on multiple ports by default thus you have to bind *rpc.mountd* to one port, then you can add an additional UFW rule to accept incoming connection on that particular port.

To do so, open */etc/default/nfs-kernel-server* and comment out the line

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS=--manage-gids
```

and add the following line

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="-p 13025"
```

13025 is just a randomly selected port, something that is available and isn't already defined in */etc/services*.

Restart NFSd with `sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server` (or `sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart` on older Ubuntu versions).

Now configure the UFW to accept incoming connections on port *13025*, *2049* and port *111*.

```
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 111
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 2049
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 13025
```

That's it. You should now be able to mount your exports form another machine. :-)

Comment: I saw that you just define 13025, why you use ufw on 111 and 2049 too? And what are 111 and 2049?Why these ports?

Comment: @Phate 111 and 2049 are default ports of NFS, see [here](http://serverfault.com/a/377172/69379).

Comment: I think you only need to open 2049 if you use NFSv4 with TCP.

Comment: Why remove `--manage-gids`?

Comment: in 16.04+ to restart NFS do: `sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server`

Comment: Post 111 and 2049 for `NFS` is handled by the `ufw`(8) `app NFS` as in the post.  like `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any app NFS`, but the `mountd`(8) needs to be set according to the port set in`/etc/default/nfs_kernel-server`, both for `udp` and `tcp`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do complex operations with new versions of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 18.04 ufw and nfs-kernel-server.

Just use this command to allow nfs on your host

```
sudo ufw allow from your_client_ip to any port nfs
```

or

```
sudo ufw allow from your_client_ip_block/24 to any port nfs
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, however, I would hardly call editing two lines in a text file a "complex operation", would you? ;-)

Comment: thank you @gokhan simpler than the accepted. i agree with JaR, not at all complicated!

Answer (score 4):

[Accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/104232/320269) is correct for old versions of Ubuntu. But now I am using Ubuntu 22, and after trying this option (was working fine in my previous ubuntus on my raspberry pi) seems that is not valid any more.

According to [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1971096).

> the /etc/default/nfs-* files are ignored by the NFS server or client
> in Ubuntu 22.04.

That means that the proposed solution of @Jar is not longer valid.

What must be done now, is editing `/etc/nfs.conf` and according to [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/es-es/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deploying_different_types_of_servers/configuring-the-nfs-server-to-run-behind-a-firewall_exporting-nfs-shares). Update this config:

```
[mountd]
#port=0
```

Uncommenting the line `#port=0` and replacing the port with the desired number (i.e. 13025 following the other examples).

```
[mountd]
port=13025
```

After this, restart the server:

```
systemctl restart nfs-serve
```

And ensure that the port `13025` now is correctly opened with `rpcinfo -p` giving and output such as:

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  13025  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  13025  mountd
    100005    2   udp  13025  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  13025  mountd
    100005    3   udp  13025  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  13025  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
```

Now must work as expected. Obviusly, remeber to open your firewall to the ports `2049`, `111`, `13025`. As explained on the previous answers:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 111
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 2049
ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 13025
```

Comment: Seems that currently for last raspbian OS still the selected answer is correct and this only apply for ubuntu.