# Ubuntu Server 22.04 NFS blocked by firewall

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, ufw, nfs

I have a set of machines with IPs as follows:

```
Server:  192.168.0.100
Clients: 192.168.0.101 ~ 104
```

I have installed `nfs-kernel-server` on the server and `nfs-common` on all clients. Firewall is enabled on all machines.

I have added firewall rules on the server:

```
ufw allow nfs
ufw allow from 192.168.0.101 to any port nfs
ufw allow from 192.168.0.102 to any port nfs
ufw allow from 192.168.0.103 to any port nfs
ufw allow from 192.168.0.104 to any port nfs
ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port nfs
ufw reload
```

Output of `ufw status`:

```
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.0.0/24
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.0.101
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.0.102
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.0.103
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.0.104
2049                       ALLOW       Anywhere
```

However, I cannot access the mount point from client machines:

```
showmount -e 192.168.0.100
clnt_create: RPC: Timed out
```

If I disable the firewall on the server, I can access the mount point:

```
showmount -e 192.168.0.100
Export list for 192.168.0.100:
/mnt/nfs 192.168.0.100/24
```

What is the issue? Why is the firewall blocking nfs even though I have added all the rules?
Any help will be highly appretiated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nfs is blocked by ufw even though ports are opened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103910/nfs-is-blocked-by-ufw-even-though-ports-are-opened)